# Iterating a Collection more than once

Tags: java, collections

I am having trouble using [`Iterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) in java.

```
it=myHash.iterator();
 while (it.hasNext()) 
        if (it.next() satisfying something) 
            do something

 while (it.hasNext()) 
        if (it.next() satisfying something) 
            it.remove();
```

I am trying to iterate hashset twice, and the first loop making `it.hasNext()` return `false`. How to i resolve this?

I tried even adding the edit as you guys suggested, still not working...

Comment: Don't put the answer in the question once you have it. I'll undo that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're reusing the same iterator - and that's been invalidated by adding new items to the set.

You should call `iterator()` again on the set:

```
it = set.iterator();
```

You can't reset the existing iterator

EDIT: Here's some sample code which shows this working:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();

        set.add("food");
        set.add("bad");
        set.add("hungry");
        set.add("neighbour");

        Iterator<String> it = set.iterator();

        // Remove any string longer than 4
        while (it.hasNext())
        {
            if (it.next().length() > 4)
            {
                it.remove();
            }
        }

        set.add("new long text");
        set.add("x");

        // Remove any string shorter than 4
        it = set.iterator();

        while (it.hasNext())
        {
            if (it.next().length() < 4)
            {
                it.remove();
            }
        }

        // Dump the results
        for (String x : set)
        {
            System.out.println(x);
        }
    }
}
```

This gives the results "new long text" and "food".

Comment: @OfekRon: Then it should be fine. Please edit again, but this time with a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. I'll do likewise, demonstrating it working.

Comment: might it be because my set is <Vertex> while yours is <String>? you think that might cause the trouble?

Comment: @OfekRon: Maybe, but without any real sample code, it's going to be impossible to tell what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, what you are looking for is a reset operation on an Iterator. Iterators are meant to be unidirectional and one-time use, as such they don't have support for reset in Java.

You can either get hold of a new Iterator instance or use [ListIterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html) interface which allows you to look backwards using previous().

Edit:

You are using remove() on the iterator which is also removing elements from the original set. In such a case you should consider making a copy of the set since you want to iterate over the elements all over again:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class IteratorSnippet {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

      final HashSet<Integer> myHash = new HashSet<Integer>();
      myHash.addAll(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));

      // make copy before using iterator with remove
      final HashSet<Integer> myHash2 = new HashSet<Integer>(myHash);

      Iterator<Integer> it = myHash.iterator();
      System.out.println("First go...");
      while (it.hasNext()) {
         System.out.println(it.next());
         it.remove();
      }

      it = myHash2.iterator();
      System.out.println("Second go...");
      while (it.hasNext()) {
         System.out.println(it.next());
      }

   }
}
```

Comment: If your myHash is initially empty, the iterator is also empty and hasNext() will return false.

Comment: it is not empty. i can tell you that

Comment: if you remove using the iterator, then entries are also being removed from your original set. You should thinking of making a copy of the set since you want to iterate over the original items.

Comment: @OfekRon check the edited example which shows using a copy to get back an iterator with the original items.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5795/discussion-between-shams-and-ofek-ron)